# tableView does not appear when centered into its parent view

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, tableview

I have a viewController with the following (static) tableView:

```
class viewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    private let tableView: UITableView = {
    let tv = UITableView()
    tv.separatorStyle = .singleLine
    tv.allowsSelection = true
    tv.isScrollEnabled = false
    return tv
    }()

    private let tableData = ["row1", "row2", "row3", "row4"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        view.addSubview(tableView)

        NSLayoutConstraints.activate([
            tableView.centerXAnchor.constraints(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor),
            tableView.centerYAnchor.constraints(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor)
       )]
    }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
            cell.textLabel!.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return tableData.count
        }
}
```

When I run the app, this viewController shows a blank screen. I know that the way I am setting up the tableview's constraints is the problem because when I set up the tableView using `topAnchor`, `bottomAnchor`, `leftAnchor`, and `rightAnchor` (and with some other tweaking) the tableview appears. Any idea why the app is behaving this way?

Comment: You have not implemented `UITableViewDataSource`  not the `numberOfRowsInSection` func. And you need four constraints to describe the location and space the view requires.

Comment: I don't think implementing `UITableViewDataSource` is a requirement here, since this is a static tableView (and thus my data source is simply the `tableData` array). I also don't need to explicitly define `numberOfRowsInSection` because that is implicitly retrieved from the length of my tableData array.

Comment: However, I should let you know that in my actual file, I have indeed implemented `numberOfRowsInsection`. I will edit the post accordingly.

Comment: Of course the table needs to know how many rows to display. numberOfRowsInsection

Comment: You absolutely do need to implement the `UITableViewDataSource`.  All you have here is a random array instance variable and two random methods which happen to have the same signature as those needed by the `UITableViewDataSource`.  You have nothing telling the `UITableView` to use your view controller to get its information which is exactly what is needed.  Just implementing the functions does nothing without setting the data source on the table.  If you put breakpoints in those functions there will never be called.

Answer (score 1):

Your table view is probably there, and centered, but you didn't define a size, so it's probably being set to zero width and height, that's why you don't see it.

You can fix this by setting a constraint on it's width and height, either to a constant or related to it's superview, depending on what you want.

Comment: what you are saying makes sense. I tried to add width and height anchors like this: `tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.heightAnchor)` and `tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor)` but it still does not show up!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this is NOT a static table view. If it were, you would not have implemented `cellForRowAt`. It is a normal table view and it needs a data source and delegate. Plus it needs a height and a width.